# Only else part is executed

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

even whel length is 0 and flag9 is null only else part is executed.can someone help me

```
Log.d(TAG, "flag8 "+ getIntent().getExtras().getString("flag").length());
Log.d(TAG, "flag9 "+ getIntent().getExtras().getString("flag"));
if( getIntent().getExtras().getString("flag")=="0"   ||getIntent().getExtras().getString("flag").length()==0)
{
 Log.d(TAG, "hidebeta "+ getIntent().getExtras().getString("flag"));
            beta.putExtra("beta", "hidebeta");
            flag=1;
            beta.putExtra("flag", "1");
                }
else {
    beta.putExtra("beta","showbeta");
    Log.d(TAG, "showbeta "+ getIntent().getExtras().getString("flag"));
    flag=0;
    beta.putExtra("flag","0");
                }
```

Comment: Compare Strings with `equals()`. Also for `null` check you should check for `null` reference.

Comment: try with `getIntent().getExtras().getString("flag").equals("0")`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Java you **cannot** use `==` to compare Strings, you *must* use:

```
if(string.equals("example"))
```

So let's use `equals()` in your conditional and optimize it:

```
String flag = getIntent().getStringExtra("flag");
if(flag.equals("0") || flag.length()==0)
```

(Also you ought to be safe and check if `getIntent()` and `flag` are not null before trying to access them.)

Read [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/513832/1267661) or the documentation on [Comparing Strings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/comparestrings.html) for more information.

Answer (score 5):

use `equals` to compare strings, not `==` (which compares references to objects)

Answer (score 5):

You should never use `==` operator for comparing two `Strings`, as it compares the actual references, not their values. Use `equals()` method instead. Hope this helps.